# ¿Cómo agrego un salto de línea en un JTextPane?

Tags: java

quisiera saber como puedo hacer un salto de linea automatico con un JTextPane como lo haria un JTextarea con la funciona "setLineWrap​"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156038/jtextpane-line-wrapping

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: @Josadec: ¡Ponlo como respuesta (en base a [answer]) y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer)! Tampoco olvides hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.